# Why does sigaltstack() fail with "Operation not permitted" only under valgrind?

Tags: signals, valgrind

I'm trying to get a multithreaded program to work under valgrind. It uses the `sigaltstack()` function in order to configure an alternate stack for a signal handler. When not running under valgrind, it runs perfectly. However, when using valgrind, the following code fails with "Operation not permitted."

```
char *sp = X;
size_t stack_size = Y;
...
ss.ss_sp    = sp;
ss.ss_size  = stack_size;
ss.ss_flags = 0;
if (sigaltstack(&ss, &oss) < 0)
{
    DEBUGF("%s()2: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
    return false;
}
```

This code is part of Rockbox's simulation feature. If you wish, you can reproduce the error by cloning the latest Rockbox tree, building a simulator, and running it under valgrind with no other options.

Comment: Valgrind is supposed to properly work with sigaltstack. There is a (very minimal) test that calls sigaltstack syscall. Please produce a minimal example that does not work, and raise  a bug on https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=valgrind  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the valgrind code, the failing sigaltstack might be a bug solved by the below patch.

Please report if it fixes the bug.
Thanks

```
Index: coregrind/m_signals.c
===================================================================
--- coregrind/m_signals.c   (revision 15901)
+++ coregrind/m_signals.c   (working copy)
@@ -1124,7 +1124,8 @@
 {
    ThreadState *tst = VG_(get_ThreadState)(tid);

-   return (m_SP - (Addr)tst->altstack.ss_sp < (Addr)tst->altstack.ss_size);
+   return  m_SP >= (Addr)tst->altstack.ss_sp
+      && m_SP < (Addr)tst->altstack.ss_sp + (Addr)tst->altstack.ss_size;
 }

 static Int sas_ss_flags ( ThreadId tid, Addr m_SP )
```

If the above does not fix it, running with the below traces might give a hint:

```
--trace-syscalls=yes --trace-signals=yes
```